# Using Azure Cognitive Searches within .NET Framework

Tags: azure, .net-4.8

I just tried using some basic code to access a QnA Maker service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/ai.language.questionanswering-readme?view=azure-dotnet

To do this, just to see something working I put the below into a MVC controller in a .NET framework solution (obviously with the keys etc replaced)

```
            Uri endpoint = new Uri("https://mysite.cognitiveservices.azure.com/");
            AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential("{my key}");

            QuestionAnsweringClient client = new QuestionAnsweringClient(endpoint, credential);

            string projectName = "{my project}";
            string deploymentName = "{my deployment}";
            QuestionAnsweringProject project = new QuestionAnsweringProject(projectName, deploymentName);

            Response<AnswersResult> response = client.GetAnswers("my question", project);
```

It didn't work, I just got messages about not being able to connect to the url

I then took the code out and put it in a controller in a MVC .NET 6 project, and it worked

I know that the framework is now old and has been replaced by what used to be called Core

My question is

(a) am I right that it doesn't work in .NET framework? and

(b) as this wasn't explicitly mentioned in the sample prerequisites should I now assume going forward that any samples won't work in .NET framework? Or if they do it's luck